# Disable future dates selection in Ajax Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have tried this code to disable future dates to be selected but it does not seem to be working.

```
public void Calendar1_DayRender(object o, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Today)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ ?

Comment: Check http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/disable-future-and-past-date-of-ajax-calendar-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/

Comment: Means, the future dates are still selectable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Extension.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="disable_future_dates" />
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgPopup" ImageUrl="~/Calendar.png" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate"
        PopupButtonID="imgPopup" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Disabling Future Dates**

In order to disable future dates we need to follow 2 simple steps.

1. Add `CSS.css` and `Extension.min.js` files just below the **ScriptManager** as shown in the HTML Markup above.
2. Set the `CssClass` property to `disable_future_dates` for the TextBox control associated with the CalendarExtender for which you want to disable the future dates.

That’s it you need to do and your AJAX CalendarExtender will now disable the future dates.